# Duplicate column combination in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Sample Table

```
first_column     second_column
1                   2
```

In the sample table above, is there a way to make a constraint in MySQL so that inserting (2,1) would return duplicate key error?

Comment: nope, you may need to use decision statement like `IF` or `CASE`

Comment: can we handle via PHP or you have to handle only via mysql?

Comment: @diEcho
I can handle it via PHP(can do check before inserting) but it would be so much better if it is handled by MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with these kind of "pairings" I try to insert in order. Like

```
INSERT INTO blah (one, two) VALUES (?, ?)
params += min(one, two)
params += max(one, two)
```

Of course this doesn't answer your question of how to set a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

No. (2,1) is not the same tuple as (1,2).

Comment: depends on the definition. normally you're right and it's definitely how MySQL will treat it. But @arvinism obviously know that. Anyway, he has to deal with a scenario where the definition is different though. Hence your answer isn't very useful, is it?

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means.